# An Application of Liouville's theorem for entire function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-geometry

Let $f:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be entire function. Suppose that f=u+iv where u and v are real and imaginary parts of f respectively. f is constant if

1. $\{u(x,y)|z \in \mathbb{C}\}$ is bounded.
2. $\{v(x,y)|z \in \mathbb{C}\}$ is bounded.
3. $\{u(x,y)+v(x,y)|z \in \mathbb{C}\}$ is bounded.
4. $\{u^2(x,y)+v^2(x,y)|z \in \mathbb{C}\}$ is bounded.

For (1) and (2) if we take $e^{f(z)}$ and $e^{-if(z)}$ then they are bounded and entire implies that f(z) is constant. Please give me some idea about (3) and (4). Thanks in advance.

Comment: 4. is just another way of saying "$f$ is bounded". Look at $(1-i)\cdot f$ to connect 3. with one of the others.

Comment: okay.(3) $|f(z)|=\sqrt{u^2+v^2}$ hence it is bounded and for (4) $e^{(1-i)f(z)}$ is bounded implies f is constant.